# MySQL user activity across time starting with last week

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, analytics

I have user activity data

```
 datetime | user | action
--------------------------
    t1    |  u1  |   a
    t2    |  u1  |   b
    t3    |  u2  |   a
    t4    |  u1  |   c
    t1    |  u2  |   a
    t1    |  u2  |   d
```

Aggregated Output should be as follows

```
t1    |  u1  |   1
t1    |  u2  |   2
....
```

if today is July 22,2015
then I need to create buckets as following

1. Jul 15,2015 12 noon - Jul 16,2015 12 noon and corresponding counts
2. Jul 16,2015 12 noon - Jul 17,2015 12 noon
3. Jul 17,2015 12 noon - Jul 18,2015 12 noon
4. Jul 18,2015 12 noon - Jul 19,2015 12 noon....

> How can I do that?

Comment: do you have timestamps like `Jul 15,2015 12 noon - Jul 16,2015 12 noon` stored in a column?or should you compute them?

Comment: t1, t2 can be any date times so need to compute these

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you are trying to get a count of user actions per day.

To accomplish that you are going to use a group by in conjunction with an aggregate function: `count`

```
Select Date("datetime"), "user", count("action")
From tablename 
Where Date("datetime") > Curdate()
Group By Date("datetime"), user
```

If you want to offset it by 12 hours you'll need to do som date math. 
[date function docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Writing this from my phone so you may have to clean this up, but replacing every `Date("datetime")` with something along the lines of the following should work

```
Case 
    When `datetime` between Date_Add(Cur_Date(), Interval -7 -12 Day_Hour) And Date_Add(Cur_Date(), Interval -6 -12 Day_Hour) Then '7 days ago'
    When `datetime` between Date_Add(Cur_Date(), Interval -6 -12 Day_Hour) And Date_Add(Cur_Date(), Interval -5 -12 Day_Hour) Then '6 days ago'
    ....
End
```

There's probably more elegant/efficient solutions, but that should get you going in the right direction

Comment: Yes but the problem is if I need to consider the day from noon time to next day noon time i.e. rather than 00:00 hrs to 24 hrs, I am considering 12 hrs of previous day to next day 12 hrs as day 1 and so on..

Comment: You can effectively achieve those buckets using Date_Add()

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: I would not have asked the question if I could have got the answer from google. Let me know if you can update or provide me a pointer to an example

Comment: I did update the answer at the end with an idea to get you started